# I need get all records from table joined where at least one case with condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join, where-clause

I have three tables:

```
cp_projeto (id, nome...)

cp_habilidade_projeto (id, id_projeto)

cp_habilidade (id, nome...)
```

I need all projects with **all** `cp_habilidade` where `cp_projeto` have one `cp_habilidade`. My actual query:

```
SELECT
    p.id as id_projeto, 
    p.nome as nome_projeto, 
    p.id_tipo_projeto,  
    p.dhPostagem,   
    cp_habilidade_projeto.id as id_habilidade_projeto,  
    cp_habilidade.nome as nome_habilidade 

FROM (  
    SELECT * FROM cp_projeto 
        WHERE (id_status_projeto = 2)
            ORDER BY dhPostagem DESC LIMIT 0, 10
    ) AS p 
    inner JOIN cp_habilidade_projeto ON (cp_habilidade_projeto.id_projeto = p.id) 
    inner JOIN cp_habilidade ON (cp_habilidade.id = cp_habilidade_projeto.id_habilidade) 
    JOIN cp_sub_categoria ON (cp_sub_categoria.id = p.id_sub_categoria)

WHERE ( 
    p.nome like '%CSS%' 
    OR cp_habilidade.nome like '%CSS%'
)
```

This returns only `cp_habilidade.nome = %CSS%`, I need it **all**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    p.id as id_projeto, 
    p.nome as nome_projeto, 
    p.id_tipo_projeto,  
    p.dhPostagem,   
    hp.id as id_habilidade_projeto,  
    h.nome as nome_habilidade
FROM cp_projecto p
JOIN cp_habilidade_projeto hp ON p.id = hp.id_projeto
JOIN cp_habilidade h ON h.id = hp.id_habilidade
WHERE p.id IN ( SELECT cp_habilidade_projeto.id_projeto 
                FROM cp_habilidade 
                JOIN cp_habilidade_projeto ON cp_habilidade.id = cp_habilidade_projeto.id_habilidade
                WHERE cp_habilidade.nome LIKE '%CSS%' )
```

Comment: this yet return one cp_habilidade per cp_project, same having various cp_habilidade for one cp_project :(